# If $|s_n|\leq C \sqrt{n}\log n$ for some $C>0$, then is $|t_n|\leq C \sqrt{n}\log n$ true?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $s_n$ be a real or complex sequence and $t_n=\frac{1}{\log n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{s_k}{k}$ be its logarithmic mean.

If $|s_n|\leq C \sqrt{n}\log n$ for some $C>0$, then is $|t_n|\leq C \sqrt{n}\log n$ true?

I tried:

$t_n=\frac{1}{\log n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{s_k}{k}\leq \frac{C}{\log n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\log k}{\sqrt{k}}\leq ...$

Comment: By the [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem),$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\log k}{\sqrt{k}}}{\sqrt{n}\log n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\log n}{\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{n+1}\log(n+1)-\sqrt{n}\log n}=2.$$ So it follows that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\log k}{\sqrt{k}}\leq C'\sqrt{n}\log n$ and hence $|t_n|\leq C\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee: Add an answer?

Comment: If I choose denominator $\sqrt{n}\log^2{n}$ instead $\sqrt{n}\log{n}$ in Stolz-Cesaro theorem, I get the desired result $|t_n|\leq C \sqrt{n}\log n$. Is this true?

Comment: @SangchulLee Could you add an answer if it is ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We begin by OP's bound

$$ t_n
= \frac{1}{\log n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{s_k}{k}
\leq \frac{1}{\log n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{C\log k}{\sqrt{k}}. $$

Since $x \mapsto \frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}}$ is eventually decreasing, we find that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\log k}{\sqrt{k}}
\leq \int_{1}^{n} \frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx + C_2
\leq 2\sqrt{n}\log n + C_2 $$

for some constant $C_2$. So we have

$$ t_n \leq 2C\sqrt{n} + \frac{C_2}{\log n} \leq C_3\sqrt{n} $$

for some constant $C_3$.